# Не применяются стили к дочерним элементам таблицы

Tags: html, css

Пишу на Vue, не применяются стили к `<tr>`, `<td>` в `<table>`. Как только делаю `tr{}`, а не `table > tr`
всё работает, хотя, по сути должно и как я писал, `table > tr` ведь должен все `tr` найти в `table`
Компонент Vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="maindiv">
        <div class="catalog">
            <table>
                <tr><td><div><p>t-shorts</p></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div><p>shirts</p></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div><p>hoodie</p></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div><p>jeans</p></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div><p>trousers</p></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div><p>shorts</p></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div><p>sneakers</p></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div><p>shoes</p></div></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap");
    .maindiv{
        margin-top: 130px;
        display: flex;
    }

    table > tr{
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-size: 18pt;
        font-weight: 100;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... `table > tr` ведь должен все `tr` найти в `table`...

Нет, не должен. Достаточно открыть инспектор свойств CSS, чтобы в этом убедиться.

Между `<table>` и `<tr>` существует ещё тег `<tbody>`, поэтому нужно указывать в селекторе - `table > tbody > tr`, чтобы получить строки основного тела таблицы (помните, что существуют ещё разделы заголовка и "подвала" - `<thead>` и `<tfoot>`) или `table tr`, чтобы действительно получить все строки таблицы, включая строки из `<thead>` и `<tfoot>`.

```html
<div><!-- тег заменён для демонстрации -->
    <div class="maindiv">
        <div class="catalog">
            <table>
                <tr><td><div><p>t-shorts</p></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div><p>shirts</p></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div><p>hoodie</p></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div><p>jeans</p></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div><p>trousers</p></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div><p>shorts</p></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div><p>sneakers</p></div></td></tr>
                <tr><td><div><p>shoes</p></div></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<style scoped>
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap");
    .maindiv{
        margin-top: 130px;
        display: flex;
    }

    table tr {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-size: 18pt;
        font-weight: 100;
    }
</style>
```